# Android studio cant download sdk with v2ray

Tags: android-studio

I am an Android developer in Iran
There are too many restrictions for the Internet
Fortunately, `V2ray`
has solved the problem to some extent, but Android Studio has serious problems with `V2ray`
no library is downloaded, it does not even allow to download `SDK`.

I have tried all the VPNs but none of them work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IN IRAN no VPN is working to use for android studio these days , only proxy is available , do it this way inside AS :

IN WINDOWS GO TO Setting >
Appearance & Behavior ->System Settings -> Http Proxy

http proxy
Manual proxy configuration

MORE :
https://dazhyarco.net/%D9%86%D8%B5%D8%A8-%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%AF%D8%B1%D9%88%DB%8C%D8%AF-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%AF%DB%8C%D9%88/#

CHANGE :
Host name >   fodev.org
Port number > 8118

[image: PROXY]

Apply AND OK
.

Answer (score 0):

Like you, I am in Iran
use this dns in your pc :
178.22.122.100
185.51.200.2
AND turn off v2ray.
or use similar site of shekan.ir

Comment: can you message me on tel
mrkhosro9818

Comment: that is shecan.ir dns, it is very slow

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @iDeveloper
even you can use the auto-detect proxy setting and android studio use the proxy setting of os that you run v2ray